# Close expandable zip on luggage without pull tag

Tags: travel, zipper

My expandable luggage zipper was ripped off on a trip.
The zipper is now permanently open, and I need to travel soon.
How can I close it without the zipper pull? Are there any hacks to do this?

Comment: consider to add a photo to show the current state of the zipper at the closing mechanism, which will enable others to provide more useful and more specific suggestions.

Comment: Do you really mean "pull tag" (the small floppy handle), or do you mean the entire slider (the part that moves along the zipper)?

Comment: I have a fleece garment where the zip fob broke off a long time ago. To close the zip, I grasp the slider with a thumb inside and forefinger outside, and slide it up. To undo it, I gently part the zip with both hands and let the slider move down by itself.

Comment: If the slider is OK, just drill a tiny hole through the upright part of the slider, if there's enough room left.  Put a thin nylon line or thin wire through to replace the tag. You can also buy replacement sliders, e.g., https://www.amazon.com/Zipper-Replacement-Slider/s?k=Zipper+Replacement+Slider

Comment: ...The problem in my case, was the loop on the slider broke, so with nowhere to attach, it wasn't possible to use a makeshift fob.

Answer (score 3):

slide a paperclip through the hole, where the original item was attached.