# How do I open a closed purse zipper with no slider?

Tags: clothing, repair, zipper

I just got a new purse and the middle pocket is zipped shut but they did not put a slider on it so I can not access it. How can I get the zipper open so I can put a new slider on?

Comment: Good luck with putting a slider on. If the purse is new but faulty, get it exchanged.

Comment: Related: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/27158/6973

Answer (score 0):

You can also watch YouTube videos. When faced with a purse zipper that lacks sliders, you can still manage to open or close it using a few clever tricks. Here are some solutions:

**Thread a Key Ring**: Find a small key ring (less than 1 inch in diameter). Pry open one end of the key ring and slide it onto the zipper fabric loop. Feed the key ring through the loop until it's securely attached. This makeshift pull can help you zip up or down⁵.

Comment: That's three answers.  Please post them separately so they may be voted upon and accepted separately.

Answer (score 0):

***Expose Fabric and Slide On****: If the zipper teeth are intact, but the slider is missing, you'll need to expose some fabric at the end of the zipper. Use pliers to pull off a few zipper teeth, revealing about 2 to 3 inches of fabric. Then, slide the zipper pull onto the fabric in the correct direction (upside-down if the zipper was open, right-side-up if it was closed). Tug on both sides of the fabric above the pull to move it from the fabric part to the zipper part⁶.

Answer (score 0):

3. **Use a Fork**: This quick fix is temporary but effective. Slide the zipper bottom onto the end of two middle prongs of a fork. On each side of the zipper, slide the bottom of the teeth evenly into each side of the zipper, zipping it closed. To make this fix permanent, sew a stopper in place⁷.

Remember, these solutions are handy in a pinch, but for a more durable fix, consider replacing the missing slider or getting your purse repaired by a professionals.